# Finding a metric preserved by the foliation $\chi_s(a,b,c)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry, foliations

Consider a Lorentzian manifold $(\zeta,g)$ with metric: $$g=\frac{dudv}{uv}-\frac{dr^2}{r^2}-\frac{dw^2}{w^2}.$$

For $u,v,r,w \in(0,1)$.

It can be derived that:

$$\Omega_s(x,y,z)=\varphi_s(x)\varphi_s(y)\varphi_s(z)\space\space\space\space{s>0}$$

defines a Cauchy foliation of $\zeta$ for $\Omega_s(x,y,z)=e^{\frac{s}{\log x}+\frac{s}{\log y}+\frac{s}{\log z}}$ and that $\Omega$ preserves the metric.

If we do surgery with $\Omega$ and embed it within the Lorentzian manifold with metric $h=dudv-dr^2-dw^2$ then we have $\Omega$ acting as a foliation of a subset of this manifold that longer preserves that metric.

We can write down a linear, bijective, continuous and smooth map between the foliations:

$$T: \Omega \to \chi$$

where $T$ is given by:

$$\int_{(0,1)^3} x^{a}y^{b}z^{c}\Omega_s(x,z,y)~\frac{dxdydz}{xyz}=\chi_s(a,b,c).$$

My objective is to determine a Lorentzian metric which is preserved by $\chi_s(a,b,c).$

> In other words, can we find a Killing vector field whose flow maps $\chi$ to itself? And what would be an example of one?

I noticed that $T$ is not only a map between foliations, it defines a symmetric nondegenerate smooth mapping so that we can obtain a semi-Riemannian metric from it.

Using that knowledge I thought to test whether that metric is preserved by the foliation $\chi$, where both the metric and foliation that (possibly) preserves it, are being obtained directly through $T$, but I'm not sure of the correct steps in testing this.